No bluetooth devices shown for Intel AC 9260, Ubuntu 22.04
I have a Lenovo ThreadRipper with an Intel AC 9620 wireless controller running Ubuntu 22.04. When I turn on Bluetooth in the Settings app, the 'Devices' list doesn't list any devices. It just sits there with a spinner which never goes away.
uname -a
Linux d8e4094-lcedt 6.8.0-49-generic #49~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC
Wed Nov  6 17:42:15 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

lsusb
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 8087:0025 Intel Corp. Wireless-AC 9260 Bluetooth Adapter

journalctl -b 0 -u bluetooth.service
Nov 21 18:16:20 d8e4094-lcedt systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Nov 21 18:16:21 d8e4094-lcedt bluetoothd[2112]: Bluetooth daemon 5.64
Nov 21 18:16:21 d8e4094-lcedt systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Nov 21 18:16:21 d8e4094-lcedt bluetoothd[2112]: Starting SDP server
Nov 21 18:16:21 d8e4094-lcedt bluetoothd[2112]: Bluetooth management interface 1.22 initialized
Nov 21 18:17:33 d8e4094-lcedt bluetoothd[2112]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.93 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
Nov 21 18:17:33 d8e4094-lcedt bluetoothd[2112]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.93 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
Nov 21 18:17:33 d8e4094-lcedt bluetoothd[2112]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.93 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_453
Nov 21 18:17:33 d8e4094-lcedt bluetoothd[2112]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.93 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_453
Nov 21 18:17:33 d8e4094-lcedt bluetoothd[2112]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.93 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_512
Nov 21 18:17:33 d8e4094-lcedt bluetoothd[2112]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.93 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_512
Nov 21 18:17:33 d8e4094-lcedt bluetoothd[2112]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.93 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_552
Nov 21 18:17:33 d8e4094-lcedt bluetoothd[2112]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.93 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_552
Nov 21 18:22:30 d8e4094-lcedt bluetoothd[2112]: src/profile.c:register_profile() :1.367 tried to register 00001108-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb which is already registered
Nov 21 18:22:30 d8e4094-lcedt bluetoothd[2112]: src/profile.c:register_profile() :1.367 tried to register 0000111f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb which is already registered
Nov 21 18:22:30 d8e4094-lcedt bluetoothd[2112]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.367 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
Nov 21 18:22:30 d8e4094-lcedt bluetoothd[2112]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.367 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
Nov 21 18:22:30 d8e4094-lcedt bluetoothd[2112]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.367 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_453
Nov 21 18:22:30 d8e4094-lcedt bluetoothd[2112]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.367 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_453
Nov 21 18:22:30 d8e4094-lcedt bluetoothd[2112]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.367 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_512
Nov 21 18:22:30 d8e4094-lcedt bluetoothd[2112]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.367 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_512
Nov 21 18:22:30 d8e4094-lcedt bluetoothd[2112]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.367 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_552
Nov 21 18:22:30 d8e4094-lcedt bluetoothd[2112]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.367 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_552
Nov 21 18:22:40 d8e4094-lcedt bluetoothd[2112]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.367 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
Nov 21 18:22:40 d8e4094-lcedt bluetoothd[2112]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.367 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
Nov 21 18:22:40 d8e4094-lcedt bluetoothd[2112]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.367 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_453
Nov 21 18:22:40 d8e4094-lcedt bluetoothd[2112]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.367 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_453
Nov 21 18:22:40 d8e4094-lcedt bluetoothd[2112]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.367 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_512
Nov 21 18:22:40 d8e4094-lcedt bluetoothd[2112]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.367 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_512
Nov 21 18:22:40 d8e4094-lcedt bluetoothd[2112]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.367 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_552
Nov 21 18:22:40 d8e4094-lcedt bluetoothd[2112]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.367 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_552

bluetoothctl power on
Changing power on succeeded

bluetoothctl scan on
Discovery started
[CHG] Controller 04:56:E5:E1:24:7B Discovering: yes
[CHG] Controller 04:56:E5:E1:24:7B Pairable: yes
[CHG] Controller 04:56:E5:E1:24:7B Discoverable: yes

The "scan on" command never returns.

Please run journalctl -b 0 -u bluetooth.service and Edit your question to include this information.

Might need to do in terminal bluetoothctl power on and bluetoothctl scan on

Does restarting the bluetooth service, By running sudo systemctl restart bluetooth change anything? Also provide the output of service bluetooth status in your question.
